# Does ATL airport subway enable entrance from East Terminal?

Tags: airports, atlanta, atl

[image]

The [map's red blocks](https://airportguide.com/terminal_maps/ATL_overview_map.png) indicate security checkpoints in the east (Concourse T) and west (Concourse F) terminal.  Can anyone confirm **from experience**, that it is possible for my ride to drop me off at Concourse F so I can take the subway to the other nearby Concourses?

Comment: Just to get it completely clear, this is about the airport in Atlanta, Georgia, USA?

Comment: @Willeke Yes, Atlanta, GA